# Enable connection pooling Spring ibatis

Tags: java, performance, spring, ibatis

I am using spring Ibatis for database management in my java application.I need to enable connection pooling to increase the performance of the application.

i added following properties to SqlMapConfig.xml file to enable the connection pooling

```
  <transactionManager type="JDBC" commitRequired="false">
    <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
      <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxx"/>
      <property name="JDBC.Username" value="xxxxxx"/>
      <property name="JDBC.Password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
      <property name="Pool.MaximumActiveConnections" value="50"/>
      <property name="Pool.MaximumIdleConnections" value="20"/>

    </dataSource>
  </transactionManager>
```

But i couldn't find any visible performance changes.Do i need to make any other changes or settings changes to enable the connection pooling?.

Following JAR files are added  in my build path

ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar
ibatis2-common-2.1.6.589.jar
ibatis2-dao-2.1.6.589.jar

Comment: I do not know how you are testing. But setting up a connection pool will not improve performance by default. If your pool size is too big it can even be worse. And if your test scripts are sequential a pool will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I also noted that you cannot set a minimum set of connections during startup. So 50 simultaneous requests at start of your test will all try to setup a database connection. Just as in the single connection case. Try using a real connection pool implementation with a DataSource. Or make sure you are testing your performance after pool has been filled.

Try using a real pool implementation. JDBC pool is quite popular and avoids some of the locking issues older pooling implementations have. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html.

Also measure your performance and make sure you really are using connection pooling. I have seen sharing of one connection over a whole application which also could explain what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using, dataSource type POOLED instead of SIMPLE.

```
<dataSource type="POOLED">
```